# How to create new form when clicking button in asp.net mvc or jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I have a card and what i want to do, is when a user click(create course) button it must generate new content(asp.net mvc) or dashboard that is empty. I have some ideas around this. Let me share below;

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 ml-auto">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
            Start New Course
        </button>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Start New Course</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="CourseName" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">CourseName:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CourseName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", autofocus = "autofocus", placeholder = "CourseName" } })

                </div>


            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Create Course</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

// Jquery
<a class="btn btn-large btn-success" id="fire" href="/Controller/Courses.chtml#">Create Courses</a>

$('#fire').on('click', function (e) {

     // dont know what to put here....?

})
```

I dont know if my logic is wrong and need some ideas around. Meaning what i want when i click the create button from the modal form it must take me to the new content(asp.net mvc). Something along this line

Answer (score 0):

Change the href value, replace the ActionResultName and ControllerName, see below:

```
<a class="btn btn-large btn-success" id="fire" href="@Url.Action("ActionResultName","ControllerName")">Create Courses</a>
```

Comment: @I an i getting an Error/Application. Here is my routing page,  // Route to Courses.

            routes.MapRoute(
                name:"Courses",
                url:"courses-registration/",
                defaults: new {controller="Home", action="Courses-Registration", url=UrlParameter.Optional}

            );

Comment: remove the dash('-') on the action, so it should be CoursesRegistration, update also the action from the HomeController. 
update:
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Courses",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "CoursesRegistration", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );